# How to integrate data incrementally in PL/SQL

Tags: sql, plsql, sql-insert, sql-merge

How can you incrementally insert data from two different table into another one ?

Let's say I have table A and B and I want to insert rows incrementally into table C. Rows should only be inserted once (if the row already exists nothing should be inserted) and not be updated or deleted in table C.

I thought it would work with a cursor in a loop and then merge and insert data if not matched. Am I completely wrong because I got the error message "table or view does not exist".

```
for x in A --cursor with data from given table
        loop
        MERGE INTO C USING A
        ON (x.id = C.id)
        WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
        insert(C.id, C.email, C.address) values(x.id, x.email, x.address);
        end loop;

for x in B --cursor with data from given table
            loop
            MERGE INTO C USING B
            ON (x.id = C.id)
            WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
            insert(C.id, C.email, C.address) values(x.id, x.email, x.address);
            end loop;
```

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8333657/using-merge-statement-inside-a-cursor

Comment: I don't get the using part -> using( select x.col1 col1, x.col2 col2 from dual ) src. Can you explain please ?

Comment: According to the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/sqlrf/MERGE.html#GUID-5692CCB7-24D9-4C0E-81A7-A22436DC968F) for MERGE statement, after the word USING you can either have a SELECT or the name of a table or view. In the linked answer, they use a subquery. In order to access the columns of the cursor, you need some kind of SELECT. Hence the `SELECT ... FROM DUAL` which always returns exactly one row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Merge takes a select statement, not a cursor. Somewhere your code has "cursor A is select...", then you try "merge into table using (A)..." However merge needs an the actual select. The correct format is "merge into c  using(select ...) A" And remove the cursor.

```
   merge into c 
   using ( select id, email, address 
             from a
         ) x
   on (x.id = c.id)
   when not matched then
        insert(c.id, c.email, c.address) 
        values(x.id, x.email, x.address);
 
merge into c 
   using ( select id, email, address 
             from b
         ) x
   on (x.id = c.id)
   when not matched then
        insert(c.id, c.email, c.address) 
        values(x.id, x.email, x.address);
```

Comment: But does this insert the rows incrementally when you drop the loop ?

Comment: It will Insert all where the id does not currently exist. But I have no idea what you mean by "insert the rows incrementally". But basically I believe you are thinking that without looping you only get 1 row. SQL does not work that way. **SQL works on the entire set at once**. In this case suppose the select A gets 500 rows and 300 of them do not exist in C, then those 300 rows are inserted. Same occurs with B.